# Tomcat7 allow access to manager app for multiple hosts configuration

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat-manager

I have configured Tomcat7 (7.0.82) to host web apps for multiple host names by adding a Host entry for each domain in the server.xml file. This works as expected. Below is my Engine definition in server.xml:

```
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>

        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
        </Host>

        <Host appBase="xxx-webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="xxx.domain.com" unpackWARs="true">
        </Host>

        <Host appBase="yyy-webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="yyy.domain.com" unpackWARs="true">
        </Host>
    </Engine>
```

Now I want to enable access to the manager app for each Host.

A user is added to the tomcat-users.xml file in conf/.

I have create a manager.xml file for each Host and placed these files in the respective domain-named subfolders in /conf, e.g. \conf\Catalina\yyy.domain.com\manager.xml. The contents of the manager.xml files are the same and contains only this information:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager" 
    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.0\.0\.1" />
</Context>
```

The manager app works when accessing it directly through `localhost/manager`, but I get the default 403 Access Denied immediately for the alternative Hosts on `yyy.domain.com/manager`; no login prompt is shown.

Am I to refer to the tomcat-users.xml file from the manager.xml file or should I somehow create a reference in the manager.xml files to the `UserDatabase` defined within the `Engine`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "Valve" tag. It's allow only "localhost" access (127.0.0.1).